# Define background image inside UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, wpf-controls

I'm new to Windows phone development and I'm having difficulties in setting up a background image inside a UserControl.I want to have it as a static resource, the image is just for that particular xaml file. It's already stored 
in the Assets folder of my project. With the code below I still cannot see my image in the preview window

Here's my xaml file:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="OrangePulse.LoginControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:OrangePulse"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="800"
d:DesignWidth="500">

<UserControl.Resources>

    <BitmapImage x:Key="splashScreen" UriSource="/Assets/loginBgd.png"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have only added image in resource collection.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="splashScreen" UriSource="/Assets/loginBgd.png"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

you have to bind this resource to any control to display image...just like if you add  blow line it will display the image..

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="splashScreen" UriSource="/Assets/loginBgd.png"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>
**<Image  Source="{StaticResource splashScreen}"/>**
```